# black screen when using python PIL paste

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to paste several images end to end and then display on canvas. I cannot figure out why this image is showing as black. Any Ideas?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=800)
canvas.pack()

grass = Image.open(r"C:\pathto\grass.gif")
water = Image.open(r"C:\pathto\ffwater.gif")

r1 = ['g','g','g','w','w','w','g','g']
row = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 800))

xx = 0
for i in r1:
    if i == 'g':
        img = grass
    if i == 'w':
        img = water
    row.paste(img, (xx, 0))
    xx = xx + img.size[0]

worldr1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(row)
canvas.create_image(0,0, image=worldr1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is black because it is only partially visible on the Canvas. I replaced

```
canvas.create_image(0,0, image=worldr1)
```

by

```
canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor="nw", image=worldr1)
```

and the full image was visible on the Canvas (the default value is `anchor="center"`).